# Formula to add or remove last text/character in a cell dependant on another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In column A I am using the following formula `=H24&".L"` to add ".L" at the end of text that appears in column B.

However some text in column B already contains "." and all I need to add to the adjacent row in column A is "L", e.g.

- if column B has "AAL" then using above formula in column A it makes it AAL.L
- however some of the text in column B already has a full stop e.g. "AV." so if I applied the same formula above it is returning the result as "AV..L"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a conditional formula like, this:

`=H24 & IF(RIGHT(H24,1)=".","",".") & "L"`